# Roslyn scripting - using aliases

Tags: c#, scripting, roslyn

I'm just getting started with Roslyn scripting, and I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding how the `Imports` property on the `ScriptOptions` class works.  I'm fine with the concept of importing an entire namespace, but if I add individual class names to the imports list, I can't use them in my script without fully qualifying them.  For example:

**Error: "CS0103: The name 'DateTime' does not exist in the current context"**

```
var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default
                                 .WithReferences(typeof(DateTime).Assembly)
                                 .WithImports(typeof(DateTime).FullName);

var script = CSharpScript.Create<DateTime>("DateTime.UtcNow",
                                           scriptOptions);

var now = script.RunAsync(null, CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

**Success: Use Fully-Qualified Type Name**

```
var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default
                                 .WithReferences(typeof(DateTime).Assembly)
                                 .WithImports(typeof(DateTime).FullName);

var script = CSharpScript.Create<DateTime>("System.DateTime.UtcNow",
                                           scriptOptions);

var now = script.RunAsync(null, CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

**Success: Import System Namespace**

```
var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default
                                 .WithReferences(typeof(DateTime).Assembly)
                                 .WithImports("System");

var script = CSharpScript.Create<DateTime>("DateTime.UtcNow",
                                           scriptOptions);

var now = script.RunAsync(null, CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

What I'd like to do is restrict the script so that it only has access to a few types within a namespace (i.e. I don't want to make the whole of the `System` namespace available, but allow access to `System.DateTime`, `System.Math`, etc), but not require the script to fully-qualify these type names when they're used.  I appreciate that it is also possible to add `using` statements to the script itself, but I'd ideally like to have the script engine take care of this for me.

I've attempted declaring aliases in the `WithImports` method (e.g. `ScriptOptions.Default.WithImports("DateTime = System.DateTime")`), but this just gives me a compilation error (`CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DateTime = System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`).

The documentation seems to be pretty thin on the ground, but the [source for the `ScriptImports` class](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Scripting/Core/ScriptOptions.cs#L92) seems to suggest that namespaces, static classes, and aliases can all be imported.  Am I doing something stupid or missing anything obvious here?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [Enfyve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2051159/enfyve)'s helpful comments, I can now access static properties and methods, but I still have to use a fully-qualified name when calling constructors:

```
var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default
                                 .WithReferences(typeof(System.DateTime).FullName)
                                 .WithImports("System.DateTime");

var script = CSharpScript.Create<object>("new DateTime()", scriptOptions);

// Still throws CS0246 compiler error...
var result = script.RunAsync(null, CancellationToken.None).Result.Dump();
```

Comment: In your `WithReferences` and `WithImports` use `typeof(System.DateTime)...` instead

Comment: Thanks, but `WithImports` only has overloads that accept `IEnumerable<string>` and `params string[]`, so I can't pass in a `Type`.

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Scripting/Core/ScriptOptions.cs#L262

Comment: I mean instead of `typeof(DateTime).Assembly` do `typeof(System.DateTime).Assembly`

Comment: Hi, thanks again, but getting the assembly referenced isn't the issue; `typeof(DateTime).Assembly` correctly gives me a reference to `mscorlib`.  `typeof(System.DateTime).Assembly` gives the same result (which is to be expected, since my code that is hosting the script engine has a `using System;` statement in the code).

The problem is that adding `"System.DateTime"` to my imports requires me to fully-qualify `DateTime` in my script, whereas adding `"System"` to my imports gives the script access to the whole of the `System` namespace and not just `DateTime`.

Comment: Sorry, was off my rocker there - I blame lack of sleep. You can include type aliases in your imports (figuratively speaking). it's `.WithImports("System.DateTime")` and then in the script you use `UtcNow` instead. (The same applies with `System.Math` and something like `Sqrt()` respectively, but the latter is more intuitive considering Sqrt() is a static method and not a static property).

Comment: Brilliant! Getting somewhere now! Thanks! My follow-up is: this allows me to access static properties and methods, but I still need to use a namespace qualifier if I want to call a constructor inside the script.  Is there any way around that (beyond putting a `using` statement in the script)?

Comment: Unfortunately not, _type-alias-directive_ actually hasn't officially been introduced to roslyn scripting afaik. see: [Github issue 7451](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7451)

Comment: You know what, I think the penny has just dropped.  I was under the impression that the imports could be used to restrict which classes a script has access to, but there's actually nothing to stop a script going `using System.Whatever;` and then using any available class (in `mscorlib`, anyway).

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.  If you want to post an actual answer, I'm happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: No problem, and I did just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access static properties and methods of a type by importing it **as if** it was an alias. eg: with `.WithImports("System.DateTime")` and then `"UtcNow"`

However, this isn't a true *type-alias-directive* (see: [Issue #7451](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7451))
and so you cannot create objects in this manner.